# Python's sympy struggling to solve simple equality

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm solving a problem and have a simple equality which I can solve on my calculator. Sympy, for some reason, struggles. These are the problematic lines of code:

```py
import sympy 
V = sympy.symbols('V')
eq = sympy.Eq(1.0 - 1.0*sympy.exp(-0.00489945895346184*V), 0.98)
sol = sympy.solve(eq,V)
```

I get no errors or warnings, it just keeps trying to compute the solution.

Anyone able to run that? Any ideas what could be causing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use brackets when passing arguments to solve you will get a solution:

```
import sympy 
V = sympy.symbols('V')
eq = sympy.Eq(1.0 - 1.0*sympy.exp(-0.00489945895346184*V), 0.98)
sol = sympy.solve([eq],[V])
```

Best regards.

Comment: Love python... Thanks!

Comment: When you put the equation in brackets a different method of solving the equation is employed (a "system" approach) and then it works. Oscar tells why it doesn't work without the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that by default `solve` converts floats into rationals:

```
In [4]: eq
Out[4]: 
       -0.00489945895346184⋅V       
1.0 - ℯ                       = 0.98

In [5]: nsimplify(eq)
Out[5]: 
     -61243236918273⋅V      
     ──────────────────     
     12500000000000000    49
1 - ℯ                   = ──
                          50
```

Then large rational number leads to trying to solve a very high degree polynomial equation which would take a long time.

You can disable the rational conversion:

```
In [20]: solve(eq, V, rational=False)
Out[20]: [798.460206032342]
```

Also if you are only interested in numeric solutions like this it is usually faster to use SymPy's `nsolve` function:

```py
In [22]: nsolve(eq, V, 1)
Out[22]: 798.460206032342
```

The `1` here is an initial guess for the solution.